# Keras semantic segmentation, infinite epoch using ImageDataGenerators

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to train a model based on the U-Net architecture. I am using two data generators (one for training, the other one for validation). However, whatever values I use for `batch_size`, `steps_per_epoch` etc, an epoch never ends.

The directory structure is:

```
-- images
   -- train
      -- img
         -- img1.jpg ...
      -- mask
         -- mask1.jpg ...
   -- val
      -- img
         -- img1.jpg  ...
      -- mask
         -- mask1.jpg ...
```

Creating datasets:

```py
train_dir = "./images/train"
val_dir = "./images/val"

seed = 42

train_datagen_params = dict(rotation_range=90,
                            zoom_range=0.2,
                            horizontal_flip=True,
                            width_shift_range=0.2,
                            height_shift_range=0.2,
                            rescale=1./255
)

train_datagen_images = ImageDataGenerator(**train_datagen_params)
train_datagen_masks = ImageDataGenerator(**train_datagen_params)

train_images = train_datagen_images.flow_from_directory(directory=f"{train_dir}",
                                                        target_size=(512, 512),
                                                        batch_size=2,
                                                        class_mode=None,
                                                        classes=["img"],
                                                        seed=seed)
train_masks = train_datagen_masks.flow_from_directory(directory=f"{train_dir}",
                                                      target_size=(512, 512),
                                                      batch_size=2,
                                                      class_mode=None,
                                                      color_mode="grayscale",
                                                      classes=["mask"],
                                                      seed=seed)


... the same for the validation generators


def combine_generator(gen1, gen2):
    while True:
        yield (next(gen1), next(gen2))


train_set = combine_generator(train_images, train_masks)
val_set = combine_generator(val_images, val_masks)
```

It seems to read the data properly:

```
Found 21 images belonging to 1 classes.
Found 21 images belonging to 1 classes.
Found 7 images belonging to 1 classes.
Found 7 images belonging to 1 classes.
```

Training:

```py
model.fit(train_set,
          validation_data=val_set,
          epochs=10,
          batch_size=2,
          steps_per_epoch=1,  # tried with 21//2, didn't work either
          validation_batch_size=2,
          validation_steps=1,
          callbacks=callbacks
)
```

I realize the problem probably lies in the steps number by I can't figure out how to make it work properly.

Comment: Do epochs actually start? Like you see the progress bar?

Comment: Yes, it does. The progress bar just fills up and then stays like that forever.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. In the [docs](https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/) it is said:

> Do not specify the batch_size if your data is in the form of datasets,
> generators, or keras.utils.Sequence instances (since they generate
> batches).

Removing the `batch_size` and `validation_batch` parameters from the fit method solved the problem.